# setting up constraint on start_date and deadline

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I added two fields to project module, start_date and stop_date. And I tried to add a code that controls the input and only saves the record if stop_date is greater than start_date. So I added this code to the project class:

```
    date_start = fields.Date(string='Start Date')
    date_stop = fields.Date(string= 'Deadline')
    @api.onchange('date_stop')
    def _onchange_date_stop(self):
    if self.date_start != False and self.date_stop != False:
        if (self.date_stop<=self.date_start):
            raise ValidationError("deadline date Should be greater than start date!")
    _constraints = [
    (_onchange_date_stop, 'deadline date 2 Should be greater than start date!', []),
]
```

Now when the deadline is before the start date, it raises validation error:

```
    deadline date Should be greater than start date!
```

and when I try to save the record I got this error:

```
    deadline date 2 Should be greater than start date!

    Error details:
    deadline date Should be greater than start date!
    None
```

But when the deadline is greater than the start date, I got this error:

```
    deadline date 2 Should be greater than start date!
```

So I always have a problem, whether if the deadline was greater or not than the start date.

Anybody can help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constrain decorator

```
@api.constrains('date_start', 'date_stop')
def check_date_fields(self):
    if self.date_start and self.date_stop:
        if self.date_stop <= self.date_start:
            raise ValidationError("deadline date Should be greater than start date!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than onchange we can use constraints... It helps to validate something when create and edit and also in change.. Here is my code and it works fine

```
date_start = fields.Date(string='Start Date')
date_stop = fields.Date(string= 'Deadline')

@api.multi
@api.constrains('date_start', 'date_stop')
def _check_date(self):
    date_start = self.date_start
    date_stop = self.date_stop

    if (date_start and date_stop) and (date_start > date_stop):
        raise ValidationError(_('The start date must be less than to the end date. ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this code worked for me too:

```
    date_start = fields.Date(string='Start Date')
    date_stop = fields.Date(string= 'Deadline')

    @api.one
    @api.constrains('date_start', 'date_stop')
    def _check_deadline(self):
        if self.date_stop <= self.date_start:
            raise ValidationError("deadline must be greater than start date")
```